# How to get file name and path out of a full path in bash

Tags: regex, bash

/mnt/googledrive/Recordings/vlc-record-2020-01-25-19h13m06s-S3510003.MP4-.mp4

I would like to end up with 2 variables:

- /mnt/googledrive/Recordings/
- vlc-record-2020-01-25-19h13m06s-S3510003.MP4-.mp4

I have tried the following:

```
    filename=${file%.mp4}
    /mnt/googledrive/Recordings/vlc-record-2020-01-25-19h13m06s-S3510003.MP4-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

```
file="/mnt/googledrive/Recordings/vlc-record-2020-01-25-19h13m06s-S3510003.MP4-.mp4"
```

If you want *just the filename*:

```
filename=${file##*/}
```

`#` and `##` removing a matching prefix pattern. The `##` means "match against the longest matching pattern", so this matches until there are no more `/` to match against.

If you want *just the directory*:

```
dirname=${file%/*}
```

`%` and `%%` remove a matching suffix pattern.  We use `%` here because we only want to remove everything after the last `/`.

Answer (score 2):

There are two buildins `dirname` for path and `basename` for a filename

```
file=/home/user/test.txt
$ dirname $file
/home/user

$ basename $file
test.txt
```

Vars

```
filename=$(basename $file)
dirname=$(dirname $file)
```